# Forcing bus creator to only accept signals from a bus object

Tags: matlab, simulink

This is Matlab/Simulink R2007a.

I have created a bus named "FOOBUS" in the bus editor, which contains three elements, say "FOO1,FOO2,FOO3".

The input port of a given subsystem is forced to accept -only- "FOO" type buses. This subsystem is saved in a library, along with a MAT file where the "FOO" Simulink.Bus object is defined.

Now, when it comes to integrating the subsystem with other blocks:

-How can I force a Bus Creator to show me the elements that comprise FOO? The thing is, that when building the FOO bus object (normally composing it using a Bus Creator configured to output a FOO bus object) I can't see the signals that should comprise the FOO bus object, and have to dive in the subsystem (or in the bus editor) to see which elements it has, and hand-write them at the Bus Creator dialog.

-Any other proposal? The aim is to have clear interface definitions that can be invoked quite simply, and not re-writing them by hand in Bus Creator blocks.

Thank you.

**Added**

Just to clarify, what I am mainly seeking is to create the Subsystem input bus without having to manually add the items (as the Bus Creator suggests AFAIK).

**Answer for R2007a**
@MohsenNosratinia provided the basis for the answer (the original answer would not work in R2007A as looks like *arrayfun* does not accept BusElements. I used the plain array approach as a workaround.

```
function addSignalsToBusCreator(busDef)
busEls = busDef.Elements;
sigString = ' ';
for i = 1 : length(busEls)
    sigString = [sigString busDef.Elements(i).Name ','];
end
set_param(gcb, 'Inputs', sigString(1:end-1));
end
```

Comment: Could you show your model?

Comment: I am not allowed to publish the model, sorry. But it's mainly a Subsystem with an input which accepts a "FOO" bus type (whose elements are well defined in a Simulink.Bus object). I don't want to manually enter the elements of the bus (in the Bus Creator dialog) in order to create a "FOO" typed bus.

Comment: I think you will find it difficult to get a useful answer then I'm afraid. I'm sure you could create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with dummy data/objects.

Comment: @Manex you should post your answer as an separate answer and title it with R2007a

Comment: However I am forced to accept @MohsenNosratinia answer because it provided me the know-how to come up with the definite solution :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do that programmatically. Simulink does not offer a way to accomplish this in GUI.
You can create a function like this:

```
function addSignalsToBusCreator(busDef)
elemNames = arrayfun(@(x) x.Name, busDef.Elements, 'uni', 0);
sigString = sprintf('''%s'',', elemNames{:});
set_param(gcb, 'Inputs', sigString(1:end-1));
end
```

And after adding the bus creator to the model, select it and run this function with the bus definition

```
>> addSignalsToBusCreator(FOO)
```

The whole trick is in the `'Inputs'` parameter of the bus creator block. It can take two dfferent type of values. If it is a string containg a number say 5, it will interpret it as if you have chosen `'Inherit bus signal names from input signals'` option with 5 inputs. However, if it contains a string with comma-separated single-quoted names it interprets it as if you have chosen `'Require input signal names to match signals below'`. In your example the string will be `'FOO1','FOO2','FOO3'`.

I have tested this in R2011b.

Comment: That would not work in R2007a as arrayfun does not accept BusElements, however that set the basis for the solution (see question), Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modifying @MohsenNosratinia's solution in order to work in **Matlab R2007a**:

```
function addSignalsToBusCreator(busDef)
busEls = busDef.Elements;
sigString = ' ';
for i = 1 : length(busEls)
    sigString = [sigString busDef.Elements(i).Name ','];
end
set_param(gcb, 'Inputs', sigString(1:end-1));
end
```